# Расширение стандартного набора полей у товаров

Tags: 1с

Добрый день, друзья! 1с для меня пока тема малоизученная и нежеланная в изучении, но по работе приходится сталкиваться со всем. Вопрос такой: как можно в номенклатуре товаров добавлять свои реквизиты у товаров? Кто с этим работал и знает хорошо?

Привожу скрины общей папки номенклатуры:

[image]

И конкретный товар со своими стандартными атрибутами. Как добавить свои поля в 1с? Это нужно для дальнейшей интеграции своего сайта с 1с и для получения/передачи дополнительной информации через пользовательские поля:

[image]

P.S. Искал в Интернете по этому поводу, ничего внятного не нашел, где бы четко было написано, как можно расширять список полей у товаров.

Comment: Дополнительные реквизиты и сведения

Answer (score 1):

Редактирование состава реквизитов метаданных производится в режиме Конфигуратора. Платформа при этом произведет реструктуризацию таблиц базы данных, изменив состав колонок таблиц.

Номенклатура - это справочник. Описание справочников как объектов метаданных найдете по этой [ссылке](http://v8.1c.ru/overview/Term_000000168.htm).
В данном случае Вам нужно добавить новый реквизит в состав данных справочника, а также вывести этот реквизит на используемые формы (форму элемента и списка).

Кроме изменения справочника, для упрощения последующих обновлений конфигурации возможно задействовать механизм общих реквизитов, который описан [тут](http://programmist1s.ru/obshhie-rekvizityi-1s-8-2/). Опять же, это все необходимо выполнять в Конфигураторе.